# How can I change the keyboard layout for the GUI? (console is OK)

Tags: setup, keyboard, gui

I reinstalled my Raspberry Pi with the latest Raspbian wheezy (`2013-05-25-wheezy-raspbian`) and modified the console keyboard with `raspi-config` to match my AZERTY setup. The layout is now OK on the console.

It is still QWERTY on the GUI, though. I tried to find the relevant entry in the menus but I just found how to set speed, sensitivity, etc. - but not the localization.

What is the proper way to set up and AZERTY keyboard on the GUI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Pi is running headless, so I can't test this, but first have a [look at this page](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Change_keyboard_layouts). Then try if you can set the keymap from a terminal:

```
setxkbmap fr
```

This should switch to french azerty layout. You can put this command into your `~/.xinitrc` if it works. There are also many other keyboard layouts available (like `be` for Belgian azerty).

**Edit**: If you want to make this permanent, you need to make sure the `~/.xinitrc` still starts the default WM and desktop. So put these lines into your `~/.xinitrc`, if it does not exist yet:

```
setxkbmap fr
. /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
```

This will run the default xinit script after setting up the keyboard layout.

Comment: Does this permanently work or is it just temporary? In the case of the latter, how could we make it permanent?

Comment: If you add it to your `~/.xinitrc`, you can make it permanent.

Comment: Added another paragraph to my answer, to clarify.